# Remove some directories from URL and append the view to default controller

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have a project when i load it it will load successfully with this URL.

```
http://localhost:8080/ci/CodeIgniter-3.0.1
```

But When I want to go to another view EX to this view:

```
http://localhost:8080/ci/CodeIgniter-3.0.1/about
```

It will show 404 Error message.

But when I goto this URL it will load successfully.

```
http://localhost:8080/ci/CodeIgniter-3.0.1/index.php/pages/about
```

I want to remove index.php and pages from url What should I do??

Answer (score 3):

to remove index.php from your url permanent use this .htaccess file
create a file with .htaccess extention where main index resides and paste this code into the file.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|css|js|install|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|update\.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

to remove **pages/about** from the url just open the route.php under applicaiton/config folder and add this line

```
$route['put_default_controller_name_here'] = 'pages/about';
```

Comment: Thanks , But what should i add instead of put_default_controller_name?

Comment: Suppose you want to open as 
http://example.com/about so for this put it as
 
**$route['about'] = 'pages/about';**

For more info you can check here
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

Comment: When i did it,I got 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: Also I have uncomment the module in httpd.conf but still i have the error

Comment: check into your httpd.conf file that rewrite module is enable or not, if not thne remove comment in httpd.conf (apache configuration file):
`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`
after restart apache server

Answer (score 0):

Edit **config.php** in your **application/config** folder set the values of some properties as follow:

```
 $config['index_page'] = '’;
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

and Create/Edit .htaccess file which is parallel to your application folder not inside and write below code:

```
    RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

By above you have removed index.php from your url.

Now to remove controller name, in your case, to remove pages from your url you have to change routes to as below code:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'users';
$route['^(:any)(/:any)?$'] = "users/$0";
```

Now, you can directly set your path by only your function name:
for example:

```
redirect('about');
```

instead of:

```
redirect(pages/about);
```